# How to change the site log URL to custom URL of the theme 50603 from Template Monster

Tags: wordpress, url, header, themes

I am using this theme:

https://www.templatemonster.com/wordpress-themes/50603.html

How you can change the site logo **URL** on the header section?

I followed a lot of steps from may sites such as the following, and nothing worked:

https://docs.oceanwp.org/article/473-change-custom-logo-url

https://crunchify.com/how-to-change-logo-url-link-for-any-wordpress-themes-including-genesis-themes/

https://docs.oceanwp.org/article/473-change-custom-logo-url

None of the above links were helpful.

I appreciate your help.

Tarek

Answer (score 0):

you can try from the admin dashboard Appearance -> Customize -> Header

generally site logos can be changed from there

Edit:
My apologies, I just realized that you are looking to change the site logo URL.

You will want to install a child theme first if there's one for your theme or create one [Child Themes - Wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

Then, you will want to dive into the original theme files and see if there are any filters within your header.php and use it to replace the anchor with a the one that you specify in functions.php in your child theme [Filters and Hooks - Wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

Do take note that if you modify the theme functions.php directly without using a child theme it will be reset everytime you update the theme.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems both links above point to the same destination. Besides, it's just a very small change, why bother creating a child theme? If I'll modify the parent theme in any case then might as well do the entire modification in the parent theme that will change the url of the site logo.

Comment: @RuiX just a note, since it's your first answer. You may want to add more detail to show how to create a child theme and how to add a filter hook, as links can become outdated/irrelevant over time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).